# Search text based on column values and return adjacent rows into a single cell

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I need some help with a Google Sheets formula.

My spreadsheet is set up as follows:

[image]
The result I need should be like in G2:

IF the text in E:E contains any of the values from A:A then return the corresponding values from B:B into G:G separated by a comma (case insensitive).

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=join(",",query(filter(A2:B4,arrayformula(regexmatch(LOWER($E$2),lower(A2:A4))),B2:B4),"select Col2"))
```

To return numbers or text use:

=join(",",query(filter(A2:L4,arrayformula(regexmatch(LOWER($E$2),lower(A2:A4)))),"select Col2"))

Comment: Amazing! Working perfectly! Thank you !

Comment: hey dot.Py! I've been using this formula with numbers and it works perfectly, however, if I replace the numbers (number of banana for example) by text, it doesn't work :( Do you know how I could do to make the formula works with text instead of numbers? 
Thank you!

Comment: @heroickoala See addition to answer.